# Information on adding opening knowledge to an engine

Tags: opening, engines

I'm writing a chess engine in C# for school purposes. As part of the assignment, I need to read something from an external document. I was thinking of reading an opening book, but I can't really find much documentation because Polyglot is used a lot of the time. I can't really use that because I don't get marks for other people's code.

Does anyone have information or a good website on how to implement a png/bin opening book in your chess engine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Polyglot opening book bin file](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/28874/how-to-use-polyglot-opening-book-bin-file)

Answer (score 1):

there are plenty of free online files of chess openings, here are a few:

https://www.pgnmentor.com/files.html#openings
http://scid.sourceforge.net/
https://www.bookup.com/ECO/chess_openings_ECO_-.htm

i could only find these links as of now. I will give you more once i find more